# possible encoding problem in column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running a daily full load to fill a table in my db. I have discovered that using

```
insert into targettable
select * from sourcetable
```

store some values in my target table that are possibly entered at source with wrong encoding. For example, one value looks like this:

```
ΞΏΞΉΞΊΞΏΞ½ΞΏΞΌΞΏΟΞΉΟΞ±Ξ½Ξ½Ξ·Ο
```

But when i execute :

```
select * from targettable where name = 'ΞΏΞΉΞΊΞΏΞ½ΞΏΞΌΞΏΟΞΉΟΞ±Ξ½Ξ½Ξ·Ο'
```

it returns no rows.

DB,table and column collation is set to `Greek_CI_AI`

Is there a way to locate and fix these values in my target table?
If not how would i make sure that these values will not be inserted in my target table. (can use sql statement or SSIS task )

Comment: Use the `N` qualifier on the string: `select * from targettable where name = N'ΞΏΞΉΞΊΞΏΞ½ΞΏΞΌΞΏΟΞΉΟΞ±Ξ½Ξ½Ξ·Ο'`

Comment: this answers the locate part. Any way to convert to the correct encoding?

Comment: If the problem column is `nvarchar`, change your load process to specify Unicode encoding for the target and specify the proper encoding for the source.

Comment: Can you post the specification of `targettable`?